# SvelteKit page URL is undefined when using it in a reusable JavaScript function instead of Svelte component

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a reusable function that uses data from the current URL to generate some output. However, when I do the following:

```js
// reusableScript.js
import { page } from '$app/stores';

export default () => {
  return page.url 
}
```

```html
<!-- Component.svelte -->
<script>
  import { script } from '$lib';
  const url = script()
</script>

<div>
  {url}
</div>
```

The value `url` is always undefined. What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: well, what does `console.log(page)` print, if you add it just before `return page.url`?

Comment: I would also argue that `script` is not a very good function name, why not call it `getPageURL` (that's what the function is doing, or attempting to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [store](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store), to read it you have to `subscribe` or use the [`get` utility function](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#get), but this will lose reactivity, so I would not recommend this, unless you just want to read the value *once*.

Otherwise export a new [`derived`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#derived) store that just gets the URL and then use it via `$`-notation. E.g.

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores';
import { derived } from 'svelte/store';

export const currentUrl = derived(page, $page => $page.url);
```

```html
<script>
  import { currentUrl } from '$lib';
</script>

<div>
  {$currentUrl}
</div>
```

If you need a function that processes the URL which requires parameters, you can create a derived store that returns a function instead, e.g.

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores';
import { derived } from 'svelte/store';

export const processUrl = derived(
  page,
  $page => suffix => $page.url + ' ' + suffix,
);
```

```html
<script>
  import { processUrl } from '$lib';
</script>

<div>
  {$processUrl('!')}
</div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to understand. I'll surely put that into practice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As `$app/stores` implies, `page` is a **store**. That means you need to subscribe to it in order to read the contained value.

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores';

const getPageUrl = () => {
  let url;
  const unsubscribe = page.subscribe(_page => { url = _page.url; });
  unsubscribe();
  return url;
}
```

---

Svelte runtime lib provides a util function [`get`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/ac7505d81bd564f6b1fafc3ad734fb36b9a9773f/packages/svelte/src/runtime/internal/utils.js#L151-L155) to help you read store value, you can use that too.

```js
import { page } from '$app/stores';
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

const getPageUrl = () => {
  const _page = get(page);
  return _page.url;
}
```